# How to insert a double quote mark in TeXStudio?

Tags: texstudio

I want to enclose my path (contains some spaces) with double quotes. 
I have tried pressing shift+' on English keyboard, but unfortunately TeXStudio translates this as two single quotes.

Shortly speaking, how to insert a double quote mark in TeXStudio?

---

Update: TeXMakerX has changed its name to TeXStudio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Shortcuts panel of "Configure TexMakerX" expand the Editor tab and the Special Key replacements; then either delete the row for the double quote or add one and pick a rarely used key (I used `§`): insert it in the first space, and insert `"` in the second and third.

Update for TeXStudio 2.3: In TeXStudio 2.3, there is no special key replacements option in the Editor tab.  Instead, you need to click User > User Tags > Edit User Tags.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a dozen years old, but I stumbled across it when I was trying to figure out why my editor *wasn't* swapping my double quote for the two single quotes.

To toggle double quote replacement on/off:

Options > Configure TeXstudio > Editor
There's an option here called "Replace Double Quotes:"

You can pick "No Replacement" to remove the auto-replace, or choose whichever punctuation is correct for your application (currently I'm seeing English, French, German, French Quotes (babel), Reverse French Quotes, Package csquotes, English (unicode), Polish, and Polish (unicode))